# Are these both reasonable ways to check on the status of pigpiod from within Python?

Tags: python, pigpio

I'm trying to check on the status of the pigpiod process from within a python script. These two methods both appear to work so far. Are there any significant advantages or disadvantages of one over the other? Are these likely to be reliable ways to do this?

```
import os, commands

def test_1():
    try:
        n = int(os.popen('pidof pigpiod').read().splitlines()[0])
    except:
        n = None
    return n

def test_2():
    try:
        n = int(commands.getstatusoutput('pidof pigpiod')[1])
    except:
        n = None
    return n

print "test 1: ", test_1()
print "test 2: ", test_2()
```

pigpiod is running:

```
test 1:  2038
test 2:  2038
```

pigpiod has been stopped:

```
test 1:  None
test 2:  None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously both work, but I would however:

- avoid to use the `os` module, but use `subprocess` instead; specifically `subprocess.run(cmd, check=True, shell=True)`,
- not use `commands` at all, as it is deprecated since Python2.6 and removed from Python3,
- finally: consider not to check that at all with a shell command and go for pigpio's own features. After importing `import pigpio` you are required to create at least one instance of the pigpio.pi class - and it will tell you if it fails to connect to the `pigpiod` daemon:

  ```
  pi = pigpio.pi()
  if not pi.connected:
      exit() # or reporting the issue
  ```

---

There are some other issues with your code. The `except` clause is catching [all exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4990718/3984613) which is something you probably don't want to do without good reason. As currently written it furthermore returns `None` if the `os` or `commands` call itself fails, say if i.e. `pidof` is not available (I have no idea if that assumption is reasonable); your test would therefore report a false negative with `pigpiod` actually running.

Comment: my goodness it looks like I've hit the jackpot; I will fire up my Pi and give this a test run tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @uhoh, sorry it took so long to provide an answer...

Comment: It's still quite relevant; I'm doing a lot of things at the same time so I can move this to the top of the list no problem.

Comment: I'm finally back into this bit of my script. There are warnings about using `shell=True` https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments. I'll try to read now about workarounds. I'm using 2.7 and my `subprocess` has no `.run()` but it does have a `.call()` which does not recognize the `check` argument, but there is a `.check_call()` for that perhaps? Those two do work, thanks!

Comment: Adding this as a comment for anyone else checking out this question: there's no reason not to switch to Python 3 to get `subprocess.run()`, by adding `#!/usr/bin/env python3` to the top of your script if you're running as `./script.py`, or by running `python3 script.py`.